# Keeping a Client Socket alive between activities using a Service

Tags: java, android

I want to enter an IP address and port of a server using editText in Android studio. When a "connect" button is pressed, the entered information should be saved and be accessible to other activities. I have used the SharedPreferences method for saving the acquired data to be accessible across activities (Is this the best way to do so?). The successful creation of a client socket (handled in the service) is checked in the Connect activity (attached below) by means of (!client.isClosed()).

My problem is that whenever the activity reaches the check in the Connect.java activity, the isclosed is nullified. I assume that the client Socket is thus destroyed when it was created in the Service and called in the Connect.java activity.

Is there a way to create the Socket and keep it alive to be used by various other activities- I require the socket to be kept alive to receive/send messages to a server which will determine to which activity the App should transition. The method of creating and closing sockets in every activity will not work as it will be registered as a new user on the server side- firmware on a module I have no access to.

Any examples/documentation/help would be greatly appreciated.

*I am very new to Android App development and Java so please be gentle if my questions are stupid :-)*

Thank you very much for any assistance.

**This is the service for handling the socket creation.**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketService extends IntentService
{
    public Socket client;
    public String ClientIP;
    public Integer ClientPORT=0;


    public SocketService()
    {
        super("SocketService");
    }

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent Socketintent)
{

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    SharedPreferences savednotes= getSharedPreferences("Socket_NAME", 
    Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

    ClientIP=savednotes.getString("IP_NAME",null);  // Get the IP address
    ClientPORT=savednotes.getInt("PORT_NAME",0);    // Get the Port number


    try
    {


        Log.d("IP", "Master IP address:" + ClientIP);       // Debug to see 
        variables in Shared preferences
        Log.d("PORT", "Port number: " + ClientPORT);        // Debug to see 
        variables in Shared preferences


        if ((ClientIP) != null)
        {
            if ((ClientPORT) != null)
            {
              client = new Socket(ClientIP, ClientPORT); // Create the Socket
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

    }
}
```

**This is the Connect.java activity:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Connect extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public Socket client;
    private EditText etIP, etPORT;
    private TextView status,IPs;
    private Button buttonCON;
    public int port=0;
    public String IP;
    SharedPreferences savednotes;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        etIP    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextIP);
        etPORT  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        buttonCON= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCON);
        status= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        IPs=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewIP);


        status.setText("Disconnected");

        buttonCON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                port = Integer.parseInt(etPORT.getText().toString());
                IP=  etIP.getText().toString();
                IPs.setText(IP);


                savednotes= 
               getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Socket_NAME", 
               Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor= savednotes.edit();
                editor.putString("IP_NAME",IP);
                editor.apply();
                editor.putInt("PORT_NAME",port);
                editor.apply();

                Intent Socketintent= new Intent(Connect.this, SocketService.class);
                startService(Socketintent);

                int i = 0xFF00EE00;
                status.setTextColor(i);
                status.setText("Connected");


                if (!client.isClosed())
                {
                    Intent relay= new Intent(Connect.this, Relay.class);
                    startActivity(relay);
                    finish();
                }

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IntentService` is not a suitable solution for your objective. An `IntentService` is destroyed as soon as `onHandleIntent()` returns.

Most likely, you do not need any sort of `Service` here. A `Service` is for when you want to be doing work when you have no UI in the foreground, and that does not sound like your case here ("Keeping a Client Socket alive between activities"). An ordinary Java singleton would work, so long as you are very careful not to introduce memory leaks.

> The method of creating and closing sockets in every activity will not work as it will be registered as a new user on the server side- firmware on a module I have no access to.

Bear in mind that your process does not live forever. Eventually, you will need to create a new socket.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at implementing a singleton.

Comment: How would I access the shared preferences, saved from the button click, to create a socket in singleton. Sorry for asking these stupid questions.

Comment: @Ryno: `SharedPreferences` might be a valid data storage mechanism for this stuff. It's not really a solution for passing things between objects, though it can have that side effect. I suggest that you simply call a method on the singleton, passing in the data, reserving `SharedPreferences` merely for persistence.

Comment: Thank you for the time taken to answer my questions, its much appreciated.